# How to get elasticsearch multi match fuzzy search to always return a min number of results

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I just dove into Elasticsearch today and I'm trying to replace my existing lucene.net implementation fuzzy search with a similar Elasticsearch query.

I'm using the Elasticsearch.Net ElasticLowLevelClient

Running this as my server via docker

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.0
```

I'm getting real close I'm just having some issues returning low value results.

I would like for my query to always return for none 0 scores.

For instance I have a document with a column value of tatra

Querying on "tat"

Returns 5 results but not tatra

Querying on "tatr"

returns the tatra result

```
var node = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9200");
var config = new ConnectionConfiguration(node);
_client = new ElasticLowLevelClient(config);

var searchResponse = await _elasticsearchService._client.SearchAsync<StringResponse>(
    indexName,
    indexName,
    // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html
    PostData.Serializable(new
    {
        from = 0,
        size = maxReturnCount,
        min_score = 0.0,
        query = new
        {
            multi_match = new
            {
                fields = "*",
                type = "most_fields",
                query = string.Join(" ", queryParts),
                fuzziness = "AUTO",
                zero_terms_query = "all"
            }
        }
    })
);
```

The query i was previously using in lucene was something along the lines of 
"tat~"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness), on fuzziness:AUTO

> generates an edit distance based on the length of the term. Low and high distance arguments may be optionally provided AUTO:[low],[high], if not specified, the default values are 3 and 6, equivalent to AUTO:3,6 that make for lengths:
>
> 0..2
>   must match exactly
>   3..5
>   one edit allowed
>   >5
>   two edits allowed

So, if you want to allow 2 edits regardless of the length of the term, don't use auto.  Use fuzziness = 2.